# Power-select not showing the selected value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My power-select will not display the selected value.

I have three power-selects in this component and two are working fine, but the third (companyType) is acting strangely - the value is blank when you first go to the form. When you select a value it sticks for that record from then on (until you refresh the page)

Template:

```
// templates/components/companies/edit-new-form.hbs
{{#bs-form formLayout=formLayout model=company onSubmit=(action "save") as |form|}}
    <label>State:
      {{#power-select
        selected=company.state
        options=states
        onchange=(action "chooseState")
        as |name|
      }}
        {{name}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </label>

    <label>County:
      {{#power-select
        selected=company.county
        options=countyNames
        onchange=(action "chooseCounty")
        as |name|
      }}
        {{name}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </label>

    <label>Company Type:
      {{#power-select class="select"
        selected=company.companyType
        options=companyTypes
        onchange=(action "chooseCompanyType")
        as |name|
      }}
        {{name.companyType}}
      {{/power-select}}
    </label>
{{/bs-form}}
```

JS:

```
// componnents/companies/edit-new-form.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  company: null,
  router: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  countyNames: Ember.computed('company.state', function() {
    return this.get('ajax').request(config.host + '/api/counties/' + this.company.get('state')).then( (json) => json.map( (county) => {
      return county.countyName;
    })
  )
}),

  states: ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'],

  actions: {
    // For dropdown handling
    chooseState(state) {
      this.set('company.state', state);
      //Ember.set(this, "counties", this.get('ajax').request(config.host + '/api/counties/' + state).then((json) => json.items));
      //this.set('counties', this.get('ajax').request(config.host + '/api/counties/' + state).then((json) => json));
    },

    chooseCounty(countyName) {
      this.set('company.county', countyName);
    },

    chooseCompanyType(companyType) {
      this.set('company.companyType', companyType);
    },

  }
});
```

And here is the route and model hook:

```
// routes/companies/edit.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    var store = this.store;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      companies: store.findRecord('company', params.company_id),
      companyTypes: store.findAll('companyType')
    });
  }
});
```

The route that gets the companyType model is:

```
// routes/company-types.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('company-type');
  }
});
```

And my models:

```
// models/company.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  companyName: DS.attr('string'),
  street: DS.attr('string'),
  county: DS.attr('string'),
  city: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  zip: DS.attr('string'),
  phone: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  fax: DS.attr('string'),
  companyType: DS.attr('string')
});

// models/company-type.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  companyType: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Looking at Ember Inspector the data for the companyType is there and is a string, per my model. When I select a value from the dropbox, the data type turns into `<svegbackend@model:company-type::ember1326:Environ Engineer`. When I select one of the other drop downs, the value stays a string which I guess makes sense since the source for those are string arrays.

So how do I get the drop down to display the value when the form loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, the `companyType` of the `company` is of type string where as the options list of the third select are of type `companyType` model. This creates a mismatch in setting the selected option initially.

Define the third power select as follows:

```
{#power-select class="select"
    selected=company.companyType
    options=companyTypesOptions
    onchange=(action "chooseCompanyType")
    as |name|
}}
    {{name}}
{{/power-select}}
```

and define `companyTypesOptions` within `edit-new-form.js` as follows:

```
companyTypesOptions: Ember.computed('companyTypes.[]', function() {
    return this.get('companyTypes').map((companyType)=> {
        return Ember.get(companyType, 'companyType');
    }); 
})
```

By this way; you will make both the options list and the selected value of type string! Do not forget if the type of the options and the selected you pass are different; you will get into trouble! Try to avoid that!

Comment: Thanks, I think I see where you are going with this, but there are two problems. First, very minor, `this.get('company.companyType.id')` should be `this.get('company.companyType')`. That works! But the second problem is this seems like a slightly complicated, non-intuitive solution to a design mistake I have made earlier. What should I have done? What is the simple, standard way to populate a drop-down from a model and assign its result to a field in another model?

Comment: can you post your models please?

Comment: i can help better if i can see models for `company` and `companyType`.

Comment: I added my models to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @BradMathews forget about what I wrote initially. I have updated the answer after seeing your models. this solves it!

Comment: I see. I guess I was naively expecting the `#power-select` helper to handle all of that. A native select is basically an array of strings. Power-select has to create a list of `<option>` tags with values that are strings then compare to the selected value which is a string to determine which gets its `selected` attribute set. Everything is already strings! Oh well. These days programming is as much or more about working around quirks in your toolsets as it is about actually solving problems which makes it all less fun.